# Different citation colour for page number

Tags: hyperref, color, citing, natbib, warnings

I try to cite a specific page in LaTeX using the following command: 
`\cite[p.~42]{Friedberg1995}`. I use `colorlinks` and I have set a blue colour for my citations. After the compilation takes place I get the following result.

**Friedberg  and Hunt** (**1995**, p. 42)

I want you to imagine that in the aforementioned, what is in bold is actually blue. The point is why `[p. 42]` isn't in blue colour as well.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,parskip=full,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}                    
\usepackage{multirow}                    
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor,siunitx}    
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}      
\usepackage{threeparttable}              
\usepackage{threeparttablex}             
\usepackage{colortbl}                   
\usepackage{longtable}                   

\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=normal,up]{caption}
\usepackage{rotate}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}              
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Customized citation style  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,~}   


\usepackage[hyperfootnotes = true]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,                 
 linkcolor=red,                              
 filecolor=darkgreen,
 urlcolor=darkred,
 citecolor=blue}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=2pt,parsep=2pt,topsep=15pt}

\usepackage{setspace}


\title{My title}

\author{Cicero \\ \textit{Roman Empire}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    DOCUMENT BEGINS    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{\doublespacing

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{13cm}
``\textit{After World War I, laws were passed severely limiting    immigration. Only a trickle of immigrants has been admitted since then ... By keeping labor supply down, immigration policy tends to keep wages high.}''
\end{minipage}
\end{center}


As it is pointed out by \citet[p.~42]{Friedberg1995} ...


}
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{chicagoa}      
\bibliography{mybib.bib}


\end{document}

}
```

and the bibliography is:

```
@ARTICLE{Friedberg1995,
  author = {Rachel M. Friedberg and Jennifer Hunt},
  title = {{The Impact of Immigrants on Host Country Wages, Employment and Growth}},
  journal = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  year = {1995},
  volume = {9},
  pages = {23-44},
  number = {2},
  month = {Spring},
  timestamp = {2013.06.19}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be very helpful if you could prepare a small, compilable document ([minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) that reproduces the error.

Comment: The post note isn't blue because natbib doesn't hyperlink prenotes or postnotes for citations - just the name and year labels.

Comment: OK, thanks Audrey. I see that you have provided a patch that can solve the problem at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/natbib-and-hyperref-for-author-year-style-produces-two-links

Comment: @PSK Sorry - I should've mentioned that post, but I totally forgot about it. I guess we can close this question as a duplicate?